# jQuery Cycle Intercepting Clicks

Tags: javascript, jquery, cycle, jquery-cycle

I'm using jquery Cycle to create a featured content slider.  In my pager I have an image from each post and a link to the permalink. I can't link to the page, but I hope this image will give an idea of what I am doing:

[image]

My problem is that when I click the permalinks in the right nav, they do not open. The links are formed properly and I'm able to right click and open in a new window. It seems like the slider is intercepting my click as a JS click and not a click on the acutaly href link.

Any one experience this problem?

here is my JS

```
    jQuery('#slideWrap').cycle({
    speed:       200, 
    timeout:     0, 
    pager:      '#featuredNav ul', 
    pagerEvent: 'mouseover',
    pagerAnchorBuilder: function(idx, slide) { 
    
    return '<li><img src="' + jQuery(slide).find(".featuredSlideImage > img").attr("src")  + '" height="50" width="75" />' + jQuery(slide).find(".featuredSlideDesc > h3").html()  + ' </li>'; 
    
} 
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/options.html, I would suggest trying the option:

allowPagerClickBubble

And setting it to true instead of its default, false.